# Full convolution vs convolution operation

Tags: neural-network

I am trying to implement backpropogation algorithm from scratch. For that I read this blog:[backpropogation](https://medium.com/@pavisj/convolutions-and-backpropagations-46026a8f5d2c)

You don't have to read the entire blog. At the end is mentioned formula to find gradients. 
[image]

Now, I am unsure of difference between full convolution and convolution here. 
**Configuration of my Network**
Following are the layers in my network

- Convolution
- Relu
- Maxpool
- FC
- Softmax
- Cross entropy
  So the derivative for cross entropy is (p-y) {p = actual probability y = true probability}. Since, I have three classes, so, my vector would look something like this :

  [0.8 0.1 0.1]
  And since the input to my FC is a vector of size 384, so, convolving it with this vector will give me a vector of size 381. And my filters are of size 384. So how can I update filter of size 384 with gradient of size 381? 
  I am a newbie and my head is quiet stuck around the concepts. Any help is much much appreciated.

Comment: What does it _mean_ to close this for "lack of clarity" with zero comments on what's lacking, given that the core part of the question is very simply phrased? "[What is] X vs Y operation?" Either they're the same, or they're different... This's _bizarre_ to say the least.